# Array of NSManagedObjects and reduce function compile but fail at runtime

Tags: core-data, swift, types, functional-programming

Using playground to simulate a problem with a core data based app turned up an issue I can't seem to understand.

```
class Pole {
var length: NSNumber!
}  
var poles: [Pole] = []  
let pole1 = Pole()
pole1.length = 1
poles.append(pole1)
let pole2 = Pole()
pole2.length = 2
poles.append(pole2)
var sum = poles.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.length } // error Could not find member 'length'
```

The property (attribute) named length is NSNumber as it is in a NSManagedObject class (entity).

Changing the Type from NSNumber! to Int! allows the line to compile and run correctly in playground.

Leaving the the Type as NSNumber! and changing the the offending line as follows:

```
var sum = poles.reduce(0) { $0 + Int($1.length) }
```

also compiles and run correctly in playground. The next step, taking this to the app, using actual NSManagedObject entity and attribute compiles but fails at runtime. The failure is 'unwrapping a nil'.

So bottom line I can't figure out how to use the reduce function when the attribute is a NSNumber and casting it to an Int doesn't seem to be acceptable.

Comment: `{ $0 + Int($1.length ?? 0) }` works? If yes, length is actually `nil`.

Comment: adding ?? 0 results in a compile error (Int is not convertible to CGFloat)

Comment: I believe it fails because I have not figured out how to cast length to an integer and the property can not be found as a NSNumber and is therefore nil when unwrapped. I'm obviously not very clear on what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSNumber` is a Foundation class that is used to wrap numbers that would otherwise be represented in a value type, so they can be used wherever a reference type is expected. Swift bridges integer literals to `NSNumber`, but not the other way around, so the original `reduce` closure was trying to add an integer literal to an `NSNumber`, getting confused, and giving you a weird error message.

Creating a new `Int` is one way to handle the problem:

```
var sum = poles.reduce(0) { $0 + Int($1.length) }
```

Or you can use `NSNumber`'s `integerValue` property, which returns the instance's value as an `Int`:

```
var sum = poles.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.length.integerValue }
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, the playground is "fixed" but I'm afraid I have some other issue in the app complicating things. I'm going to ask another question rather than keep spinning this one. I tried to give you an up vote but I guess I don't have enough reputation.